# Seagate external HDD has wildly varying performance

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, external-hdd

My Seagate external HDD came with a NTFS partition, and after a few GB written it started to have awful performance, writing at less than 1 MB/s, so I tried formatting it as Ext4, but the performance still wasn't great. So I formatted it again as NTFS and it got really fast, writing at 70 MB/s, but as soon as I copy files from an Ext4 partition to the external drive it starts to hang and gets really slow. Can anyone tell me what might be going on?

When I run the benchmark the access times also vary wildly, going from 10 miliseconds to 100 miliseconds.

Comment: You didn't say what size HDD, or if it's USB2 or USB3. If it's 2TB or larger, you'll need to use a GUID partition table, and you may need to use a power adapter for the external case, or a **powered** USB hub.

Comment: It's USB3, 1 TB.

Comment: It may be a USB problem. Are you plugging the drive into a USB3 port? Does your external case allow the use of an external power adapter? Do you have a powered USB hub? If you dual-boot with Windows, how does the drive work there?